# Multiple sites under the same hostName possible?

Tags: asp.net, routes, sitecore, sitecore6

**UPDATE:** This issue was caused by Aliases. See my answer below.

I am attempting to implement a multi-site environment in Sitecore 6.5 that looks something like the following:

[image: Sitecore tree]

As you can see, there is a main site under the "Corporate" folder, and several sub-sites under the "Microsites" folder. The issue I am experiencing is that I need the sub-sites to exist within the same domain. For example:

- mysite.com/ (Main site)
- mysite.com/subsite (Subsite 1)
- mysite.com/subsite2 (Subsite 2)

So far, here is how I have it configured in my sites collection:

```
<sites>
    ...
    <site name="subsite" hostName="mysite.com" virtualFolder="/subsite" physicalFolder="/subsite" rootPath="/sitecore/content/microsites/subsite" startItem="/home" ...
    <site name="subsite2" hostName="mysite.com" virtualFolder="/subsite2" physicalFolder="/subsite2" rootPath="/sitecore/content/microsites/subsite2" startItem="/home" ...
    <site name="website" hostName="mysite.com" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content/corporate/" startItem="/home" ...
    ...
</sites>
```

For the most part, Sitecore is able to successfully deliver me to the sub-sites based on the virtualFolder path alone. However, the issue I am experiencing is that if I have an item with the same name in my subsite as I do in the main corporate site, Sitecore will always attempt to load the Item from the main corporate site.

For instance, say I have an item called **About** that exists as a child of the main site as well as in one of my sub-sites. By navigating to **mysite.com/subsite/about**, the URL will remain the same, however, Sitecore will serve up the About page from the main site. If the item is called **AboutUs** in the subsite's tree, everything works great.

Any ideas on how to work around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, mystery solved... whew.

As it turns out, my site configuration was correct, however, I had **Aliases** set up for most of the first-level items such as **About** that were pointing to the main site. Removing them solved the problem. Thanks so much for your time if you were perusing this question.

Comment: I think you should accept this as an answer so that the other see it immediately after coming to this thread.

Comment: Will do, Yan :). I have to wait another 15 hours until it will let me.

Answer (score 1):

Let me give a try:

```
<sites>

<site name="subsite" hostName="mysite.com" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/subsite" rootPath="/sitecore/content/microsites/subsite" startItem="/subsite" ...

<site name="subsite2" hostName="mysite.com" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/subsite2" rootPath="/sitecore/content/microsites/subsite2" startItem="/subsite2" ...

<site name="website" hostName="mysite.com" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content/corporate/" startItem="/home" ...

</sites>
```

*I have not tried this code on my local machine, as I need to create this structure in my local website.

Try this and kindly let me know.

Reference: http://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Articles/Administration/Configuring%20Multiple%20Sites/Adding%20New%20Site/Examples.aspx

Comment: Thanks very much! I'm sure that would have worked as well, however, as it tuns out, my issue was unrelated to the site config.